# Nuxt3 component library as a module

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt-module

Looking for some help on a Nuxt module.

I have a component library (the module) which uses an npm package, `flat`, https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat

When I use the component library in isolation, it works as expected, but when I import the component library as a package and try to use one of the components (which uses a composable which relies on the `flat` package) then the page loads and then a split second later it shows an error:

`The requested module '/_nuxt/node_modules/flat/index.js?v=e21f50a7' does not provide an export named 'flatten'`

I suppose it is to do with my module configuration, I have this in my setup method:

```
export default defineNuxtModule({
  hooks: {
    'components:dirs'(dirs) {
      dirs.push({
        path: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/components', import.meta.url)),
      });
    },
    'imports:dirs'(dirs) {
      dirs.push(fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/composables', import.meta.url)));
    },
  },
});
```

The failing import is part of a composable file which one of my components uses. It seems as though maybe some mapping or configuration might need to be added.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I have answered your question below, but if you still encounter the issue, you can upload your exact configs on a GitHub repo. I will be happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have posted, doesn't reproduce on my machine. I tried with nuxt versions `3.0.0`, `3.1.2` and `3.2.3`. From [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/13247), the issue is either solved by:

- Updating all of the packages (or at-least nuxt specific ones)
- Or You can try adding following code in your nuxt config.

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  alias: {
    'flat': 'flat/index.js',
  },
})
```